# How to filter out a geometry from another geometry in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have a shapefile out of which I need to filter out another shapefile. The .filterBounds() function filters to the second shapefile, which is actually what I need to "delete". How do I do this? Here's the code I'm working on:

```
// sampling pixels for control group: (MA) - (PES)

var MApes = MA.filterBounds(PES);

var MAnot = MApes.not(); // this was a solution I found in another thread, but GEE didn't recognize the function

// lossyear Atlantic Forest without the PES area

var lossyearMA = ee.Image("UMD/hansen/global_forest_change_2020_v1_8")
  .select(['lossyear'])
  .clip(MAnot); //
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By reading the documentation about 'filterBounds' in a Feature Collectiom:

https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-featurecollection-filterbounds

I can write a [little script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/c6550d95cddacc1f8c2d5c96e19843ba) where it can be visualized how it works.

```
var table = ee.FeatureCollection("users/joseguerreroa/vector_files_utah/polygon8");

var geometry = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-111.38082277773897, 40.18818122317403],
          [-111.47969973086397, 40.159849688822554],
          [-111.38906252383272, 40.09369678520451],
          [-111.24212038516085, 40.09789888344406],
          [-111.20916140078585, 40.15670101046775],
          [-111.22976076602022, 40.26262620922357],
          [-111.13088381289522, 40.3118616801841],
          [-111.34649050234835, 40.319191553943334],
          [-111.41790163516085, 40.244808803160254]]]);

Map.addLayer(table, {'color':'red'});
Map.addLayer(geometry, {'color':'blue'});
Map.centerObject(table);

var new_table = table.filterBounds(geometry);

Map.addLayer(new_table);

print(new_table.geometry());

var intersect = geometry.intersection(new_table.geometry());

Map.addLayer(intersect);
```

Above script uses a Feature Collection with 8 features and it is filtered by a geometry with only one feature. They look as follow:

[image]

After running script in GEE code editor, it results, as expected, in a darker feature of following image.

[image]

However, it can be observed in following image that 'filterBounds' works in a different way related to 'intersection' method.

[image]